# Why are .io domain names so expensive?

Tags: domains, domain-registration, top-level-domains

The TLD `.io` is significantly more expensive than traditional TLDs, such as `.com`:

[image]

Why is there such a price difference? How is the pricing for domains determined?

Comment: As you probably know .IO originally belonged to the British Indian Ocean Territory, and thus ultimately to the United Kingdom. Whoever they chose to sell it to decides on the price. Maybe they feel the domain is worth more because it happens to match the name of one of Jupiter's moons?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about **[webmastering as defined in the FAQ](http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic)**.

Comment: There's no competition. We're spoiled to have cheap .coms and .nets.

Comment: Related: [If ICANN only charges 18¢ per domain name, why am I paying $10?](http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/61467/if-icann-only-charges-18%C2%A2-per-domain-name-why-am-i-paying-10)