# How is Godaddy able to sell domains for as cheap as $1?

Tags: domains

I read [this](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/61467/if-icann-only-charges-18%C2%A2-per-domain-name-why-am-i-paying-10) question which made me realize why domains are worth around $10. Almost a year ago, I purchased a domain from Godaddy for $1. Godaddy sells.com's very cheap for the first year. How are they able to do so?

Comment: They take a loss on it in the hopes they can get more business from you which is much more profitable.

Answer (score 6):

As [John Conde](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/users/1253/john-conde) says, they are making a loss, and making up for it when they auto-renew your credit card. Most users do not know how to transfer a domain away from a registrar once it's registered.

Also, they are selling addon services.

It's the old adage, 'Get them in the door, then sell them everything'