# Why do some top level domains cost more and where does the money go?

Tags: domains, dns, top-level-domains

I have recently acquired a cheap top level `.sexy` domain for around only €30 a year. When I look at the pricing of other new top level domains such as `.security` they cost much more at a whopping €2850+ a year.

*Questions(s):*

- Who makes money on the sale of domains?
- Where does my money go after purchasing a domain?

Comment: I do not see how this is a duplicate. My original question is who receives the money, not why some domains costs more. Edits have changed it a bit too much from what I actually want to know.

Comment: How so? you want to know where your money goes? and why some domains cost more than others? your edited question highlights the key parts.

Comment: "who is the overall distributor of TLDs and how much share of the price do they receive?" Is the only question I asked originally, at least that is the only questionmark I can find. I do not want to ask a blank question without context, that is why I shared how I came up with it.

Comment: John is right, the way your question was written and even the way I edited is still duplicate. Your asking whom makes the money, the question and even the top answer clearly displays that.... the registry... i.e Verisign, Nominet, Go.Global etc

Comment: I've left my own answer http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/a/104433/20604 which may help... summary, the registrar normally makes a tiny percentage, the majority goes to the wholesaler, and ICCAN is non profit and will only charge to cover running costs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A bunch of new registries are in control of the new TLDs.  They can charge whatever they like for the TLDs.  To answer your question, the registry controlling the domain is the one making the money, that is where much of it ends up.  Some ends up with the retailer, but domain selling is pretty competitive so you can almost be certain there won't be huge markups at the retail end.

[Here is an article](http://domainnamewire.com/2017/03/07/much-costs-run-domain-name-registry/) about how much it costs to run a registry

And [here is another article](http://domainnamewire.com/2017/03/07/yikes-death-spiral-new-top-level-domain-names/) about the price rises of some TLDs